# {Yocto} "opkg_install_cmd: Cannot install package <package_name>." Errors

Tags: build, task, yocto, rootfs

I am working with YOCTO project and running into the problem that made the build progress fail. The failure was at a last task *do_rootfs*

Below is the error log:

```
ERROR: Unable to install packages. Command '/home/yocto/Work/skrzg1h_iWg21m_QtHmi/build/tmp/sysroots/x86_64-linux/usr/bin/opkg-cl -f /home/yocto/Work/skrzg1h_iWg21m_QtHmi/build/tmp/work/iwg21m-poky-linux-gnueabi/core-image-weston/1.0-r0/opkg.conf -o /home/yocto/Work/skrzg1h_iWg21m_QtHmi/build/tmp/work/iwg21m-poky-linux-gnueabi/core-image-weston/1.0-r0/rootfs --force_postinstall --prefer-arch-to-version   install locale-base-en-us locale-base-en-gb' returned 255:
Unknown package 'locale-base-en-us'.
Unknown package 'locale-base-en-gb'.
Collected errors:
 * opkg_install_cmd: Cannot install package locale-base-en-us.
 * opkg_install_cmd: Cannot install package locale-base-en-gb.

ERROR: Function failed: do_rootfs
ERROR: Logfile of failure stored in: /home/yocto/Work/skrzg1h_iWg21m_QtHmi/build/tmp/work/iwg21m-poky-linux-gnueabi/core-image-weston/1.0-r0/temp/log.do_rootfs.31252
ERROR: Task 7 (/home/yocto/Work/skrzg1h_iWg21m_QtHmi/build/../poky/meta/recipes-graphics/images/core-image-weston.bb, do_rootfs) failed with exit code '1'
NOTE: Tasks Summary: Attempted 5097 tasks of which 5096 didn't need to be rerun and 1 failed.
No currently running tasks (5096 of 5098)

Summary: 1 task failed:
  /home/yocto/Work/skrzg1h_iWg21m_QtHmi/build/../poky/meta/recipes-graphics/images/core-image-weston.bb, do_rootfs
```

If you guys already run into this problem also, kindly support me how to fix this.
Thanks.

Comment: Which yocto version is this?

Comment: hi @jku : PV="3.10+git34547b2a5032ce6dca24b745d608d2f3baac187f"

Comment: That looks like the version string of a specific recipe. I'm asking about the Yocto version -- as in https://wiki.yoctoproject.org/wiki/Releases. If you use Yocto from git, git the branch name is the right answer. Otherwise you can try `bitbake -e core-image-minimal|grep ^DISTRO_VERSION`

Comment: Sorry @jku : I used the yocto project DISTRO_VERSION="1.6.1".
I figured out this problem. It caused by the lack of eglibc-locale package. Thank you.

Comment: By the way, sometimes just **cleansstate** and rebuild again, though wasting a little bit time but it works well weirdly :D